# Passing Dynamic parameter using STRING_SPLIT to IN parameter

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, split, where-clause

I am using SQL Server 2016 and I have to pass dynamic values to `IN` parameter.

For this reason, I am using a `SPLIT_STRING()` function that returns a table of items from a given comma-delimited string. It returns all the records if I passed the value like this `(4,6,8)` to the `@Cylinders` parameter.

```
Where CarCylinders IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Cylinders, ','))
```

But I have requirements where I want to pass `Null` value to the `@Cylinder` parameter. So that query returns all the records and ignores the condition.

I don't want to use dynamic SQL solution as the query is very complex and there are more than 20 input parameters.

Comment: You don't want to use a dynamic solution - but that that might just be what you should use. See [Erland's discussion](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `AND`/`OR` logic:

```
where @Cylinders is null or CarCylinders IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Cylinders, ','))
```